# ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy vs ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

What is the optimal write model strategy to use to achieve the Upsert requirement at Target Mongo collection. There are set of columns value from Kafka topic is identified as unique. Same columns are marked as unique index in target collection.
using the ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy the Unique index columns are identified under "_id"
Using the ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy how this works ?
What is the optimal write model strategy as we have 100+ columns from kafka topic?

Tried using the ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy the Unique index columns are identified under "_id" . Is this optimal way as we have 100+ columns in Kafka topic